# Linux error when resume from RAM

Tags: linux, ubuntu, bios, sleep, sysrq

The last two times that I have resumed my laptop from sleep, it has hung and given me this set of errors:

```
[drm:atom_op_jump] *ERROR* atombios stuck in loop for more than 1sec aborting
[drm:atom_execute_table_locked] *ERROR* atombios stuck executing E692 (len 460, WS 0, PS 4) @0xE6D3
hda_intel: azx_get_responce timeout, switching to single_cmd mode: last cmd=0x01170700
ata6: softreset failed (device not ready)
ata4: softreset failed (device not ready)
[drm:atom_op_jump] *ERROR* atombios stuck in loop for more than 1sec aborting
[drm:atom_execute_table_locked] *ERROR* atombios stuck executing E692 (len 460, WS 0, PS 4) @0xE6D3
```

The last two messages repeat two more times. The first time this happened, Linux's Magic SysRq worked and did a soft reboot, and after that everything was fine till it went to sleep again. It wakes up and gives me this. Here are the laptop stats:

- Toshiba Satellite L455D-S5976
- AMD Sempron SI-42 Processor
- 2GB DDR2 RAM
- HD TruBrite Display
- ATI Radeon Graphics (integrated)
- Running Ubuntu 10.10 32 bit

I'm not sure about the hard drive, but its a 250GB drive with one NTFS partition, two Hidden NTFS, one Linux Swap, and one Ext4. Can someone tell me whats wrong with my laptop?

Note: This only happens when I close the screen. My computer doesn't go to sleep with the screen open.

Comment: Year of Linux on the desktop, I say!

Comment: Yeah. This is the first time I've had hardware issues with Linux. I've had plenty of software failures, but Linux has had good hardware support for all my hardware.

Answer (score 0):

[Get thee to freedesktop Bugzilla!](https://bugs.freedesktop.org/show_bug.cgi?id=32066)